# How to add subdomain at runtime in servlet and tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, runtime, subdomain

I have www.mydomain.com. How to add subdomain1.mydomain.com at runtime where it should refer to another already deployed web application?

Answer (score 0):

If You have own server You should go to named or bind and in zone file add:

```
* IN CNAME mydomain.com.
www.* IN CNAME mydomain.com.
```

or if using only by ip

```
* IN A ip.ip.ip.ip
```

Restart bind and wait for broadband dns.
Next if you go to blabla.mydomain.com and system redirect to default vhost 
this mean You wildcard is active.

Now your need script when user create blog. If your domain is mydomain.com and redirect to main directory on server `/var/www/application`
You can create in `/var/www/services/` and now what You should to do:

When user create new blog You need create the same name of folder in

```
/var/www/services/user1
```

and in
/var/www/.htaccess add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?user1.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !services/user1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ services/user1/$1 [L]
```

when another usr add blog with ame user2
create folder `/var/www/services/user2`
and add to .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?user2.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !services/user2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ services/user2/$1 [L]
```

etc, etc

Your .htaccess should like :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?user1.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !services/user1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ services/user1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?user2.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !services/user2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ services/user2/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Host appbase="webapps/ROOT/subdomain1" autodeploy="true" name="subdomain1.mydomain.com" unpackwars="true" xmlnamespaceaware="false" xmlvalidation="false">
<Context docbase="/usr/local/software/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/subdomain1" path="" reloadable="true"></Context>
<Context antijarlocking="false" antiresourcelocking="false" docbase="/usr/local/software/tomcat7/webapps/manager" path="/manager" privileged="true" reloadable="true"></Context>
</Host>
```

Try modify the server.xml file available in ${catalina.home}/conf/server.xml or tomcat_installation/conf/server.xml

Do not forget restart server :)

Comment: Is there any way to do that at runtime? I mean the user of the website can select his own subdomain.

Comment: No, I mean something similar to what exist in wordpress for example. Any user can create his own blog with hisname.mydomain.com at runtime without any need from website administrator.

Comment: Do U have active wildcard on server ?

Comment: Actually, I don't know what is the "active wildcard". How can this accomplish what I need?